# Xcode 6 ARM architecture reference

Tags: xcode6, xcode6.1

Previously it was located at:

Xcode 4.2: /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTISAReferenceGuide.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ARMISA.pdf
Xcode 4.3: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/DTISAReferenceGuide.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ARMISA.pdf

But I can't find it now with XCode 6 at either path. Is it renamed or moved somewhere else?

Comment: Do you know where it is now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found a solution for 6.1.1 using searching inside a bundle as **wjk** suggested
The only difference that I searched for explicit filename and Xcode version is different as I mentioned.

find /Applications/Xcode.app -name 'ARMISA.pdf' -print

The output is
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ARMISA.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I just searched through Xcode 6.1 (build 6A1046a) using the UNIX `find` tool like so:

```
find /Application/Xcode.app -name '*.pdf' -print
```

As the above command produced a lot of output, I redirected it to a file and opened it into my editor. I then went through the results line-by-line and found nothing like what you’re describing. It seems Apple removed it entirely. (Shame, too — it certainly seems useful, even though I have never heard of it before now.)